# Sharing watch face from simulator and then on importing into simulator show error

Tags: swiftui, simulator, watchface

i have created a watch face on iOS simulator (in fact tried creating many different types). then i have exported via share option. Now when i add this watch face into xcode and call

`addWatchFace` code does not throw error, but when Apple Watch app is opened there i get this  error ""This watch face is not available on your Apple watch".
i am using Xcode 14.3.1 with simulator iOS16.4 and watch simulator 8 series OS 10

so i want to find out why on simulator these not working.

created multiple watch faces, tried applying on different versions of paired watches and iOS simulators.

[creating face on Apple watch simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHF62.jpg)

[Applying exported/shared watch face in simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCHN3.png)

On Physical devices (iPhone and Watch) these work fine.

**How to reproduce ?**

1. From simulator Open Apple watch app and share any face (create your own or share existing)
2. Share via email or airdrop
3. Drag this face into simulator again
4. Error will be shown that face is not available for this device.
5. If try to apply using below code, same error occur
   `CLKWatchFaceLibrary().addWatchFace(at: url)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.